# put my polyline in an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, svg

Ok Guys here is what I have. I am looping through each dash in the polyline which I rounded to 984, its really like 984 and some change. But anyways I am seeing no movement, what I want is the lines to move around the polyline in unison. Can anyone see why this polyline is moving as the dashoffset continuously is being changed. Then i re-initate the function. Does anyone see why this guy isnt moving at all? please and thanks. I could be really fudging this up but thought Ide see if I can get another input.

```js
  loop();
  
  function loop(){
    
    var counter = 0;
    var polyline = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i< 984; i++){
      
      polyline[0] = getElementById('poly');
      
      polyline[0].style.strokeDashoffset = i;
      
    }
    loop();
  }
```

```html
 <svg id="square" width="900" height="400">
          <polyline id="poly" style="stroke-linejoin: round; fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width:8;stroke-dasharray:492.44289 492.44289;
  stroke-dashoffset:0;"
 3         points="0,200
                   450,0
                   900,200
                   450,400
                   0,198.4" 
                    />
        </svg>
```

Comment: Could you please update the question with a clear explanation of what result you're looking for? Something like [marching ants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_ants)?

Comment: The polyline creates a diamond shape and right now the two sides opposite of each other and currently filled. I want those two lines to move along the polyline infinitely.

Comment: I realize the counter is useless, I deleted it already

Answer (score 1):

That infinite loop you have there seems pretty useless. You'd want to use `requestAnimationFrame` instead of calling the loop directly, and the loop doesn't seem to do anything useful (just sets the dashoffset to the last `i` value). But you don't even have to use scripting to animate the stroke.

```
<svg viewBox="-8 -8 916 416">
    <polyline points="0,200
                   450,0
                   900,200
                   450,400
                   0,198.4" />
</svg>
```

and css:

```
polyline {
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    fill:red;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:8;
    stroke-dasharray:492.44289 492.44289;
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: march;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes march {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    50% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 492.44289;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 984.88578;
    }
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rz0udx2v/). And if you want to get rid of the ugly left hand corner you might try using a polygon instead of a polyline, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rz0udx2v/1/).